# connecting 4 scales to microcontroller for use as dog force plate

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to build a system to measure the force distribution between the 4 legs of a dog. I plan to use this method:

http://www.rehabtools.org/scales.html

This setup seems to be for 1 scale. I want to use 1 scale for each leg, so that adds up to  4 scales. I assume I need 4 amplifiers, but can I connect those 4 to one microcontroller?

I currently have the Arduino Uno coming, will that work?

The connection from the 4 legs of the scale to the load amplifier I understand. But how do I go about having the 4 readings and then getting them in the software program?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use the search terms `arduino load cell` in your research

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the links in the tutorial you linked to, you will find

- this [library for interfacing the HX711 load-cell amplifier](http://www.rehabtools.org/uploads/5/4/2/3/54237171/hx711-master.zip)
- this [example sketch](http://www.rehabtools.org/uploads/5/4/2/3/54237171/load_cell_website_v2.ino) for reading the scale

The library uses a bit-banging method (`pulseIn()`) for communicating
with the amplifier. This method can work with *any* of the Arduino
digital pins. In the example sketch you have the instantiation:

```cpp
HX711 scale(3, 2);
```

where the numbers (3, 2) tell the library the pins you want to use.

Given all this, you should be able to interface four identical scales
simply by using four separate pairs of pins. For example:

```cpp
HX711 scale1(3, 2);
HX711 scale2(5, 4);
HX711 scale3(7, 6);
HX711 scale4(9, 8);
```

The adapt the example sketch to read all the scales.